# Congruence system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Could you please help me to find out the solution of the system

$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
x&\equiv&2& (\textrm{mod} \ 5) \\
x&\equiv&3& (\textrm{mod} \ 4) \\
x&\equiv&9& (\textrm{mod} \ 6)
\end{array}
$$

Using the Chinese reminder theorem. Here is my progress: the numbers $b_1=2$, $b_2=3$ and $b_3=3$ are particular solutions of each congruence, respectively. We compute
$$
y_1= 6\cdot4=24, y_2= 5\cdot6=30, y_1= 5\cdot4=20
$$

The theorems guarantees that the following congruences have solution

$$
24x_1\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 5), 30x_2\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 4),
20x_3\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 6),
$$
ie.
$$
4x_1\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 5), 2x_2\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 4),
2x_3\equiv1 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 6),
$$

I can get $x_1=4$, but what about $x_2$ and $x_3$?

The answer, according to Wolfram Alpha is $x\equiv27 \ (\textrm{mod} \ 60)$

Answer (score 2):

The congruence $2x_2\equiv1\pmod4$ has no solutions as an odd number cannot be a multiple of $2$.

One needs to decompose the system so that the moduli (in our case $5, 4$, and $6$) are mutually prime, which is the hypothesis of Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Now observe that the congruence $x\equiv9\equiv3\pmod6$ is equivalent with $$x\begin{cases}\equiv0\pmod3\\\equiv1\pmod2\end{cases},$$ by Chinese Remainder Theorem. Moreover, the congruence $x\equiv1\pmod2$ is implied by another congruence $x\equiv3\pmod4$. So we can reduce the original system to
$$
x\begin{cases}\equiv2\pmod5\\\equiv3\pmod4\\\equiv0\pmod3\end{cases}.
$$

I suppose you can continue from here.

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
x&\equiv&2& (\textrm{mod} \ 5) \\
x&\equiv&3& (\textrm{mod} \ 4) \\
x&\equiv&9& (\textrm{mod} \ 6)
\end{array}
$$
$x=5k+2$

So $5k+2 \equiv 3 (mod 4)$

$5k \equiv 5 (mod 4)$

So $k \equiv 1 (mod 4)$

Or $k=4m+1$

$\therefore x=5(4m+1)+2$

Or $x=20m+7$

Now, $20m+7 \equiv 9 (mod 6)$

$\Rightarrow 20m \equiv 2 (mod 6)$

$20m \equiv 20 (mod 6)$ (adding 18)

So $m \equiv 1 (mod 3)$

Or $m=3p+1$

$x=20(3p+1)+7$

$x=60p+27$

$\therefore x \equiv 27 (mod 60)$

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is a long but effective way of solving a system of congruences not more than 4 otherwise it becomes tedious.

Comment: I needed to use Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Above does use CRT, but *pairwise* $(2\,$ at a time). It solves the first pair to get the equivalent congruence $\,x\equiv 7\pmod{20},\,$ then it solves that paired with last $\,x\equiv 9\pmod{6}\,$ to get $\,x\equiv 27\pmod{60}.\ $ This is a common convenient way to apply CRT.